# Statistics for posts from unregistered versus registered accounts

Tags: support, feature-request, status-completed, moderation, site-analysis

This request stems from a related discussion, [Banning Unregistered Users](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2050/42). According to a [similar question on Meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192195/243394), the registered/unregistered status is not available in the SE data explorer, so I'm requesting summary statistics similar to the ones provided in [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/192199/243394) and [Meta.ServerFault](https://meta.serverfault.com/a/5839). Ideally, the statistics would be for at least the past year as opposed to the past 60 days.

To be specific, I'll copy verbatim the request at Meta.SE, since mine is essentially the same:

> I would like to have statistics for the quality of posts coming from
> unregistered versus registered accounts on my site.
>
> It is my suspicion that people who are willing to put out the effort
> to register an account will also put more effort into writing good
> questions; I'd like to see some evidence for or against this.
>
> I also suspect that on my site the vast majority of good questions and
> answers come from registered users, but again I'd like to see some
> data.
>
> Is this already possible through the Data Explorer? If so, how? If not
> consider this a feature request.

Comment: Apologies if this is a very basic question, but how is it possible to have an account but be unregistered? It's many years since I opened my own account so I don't recall the procedure.  In the Help Centre there is information on accounts but I couldn't find anything about registration.

Comment: @AdamBailey: On an unregistered user's page, you can see a mark that indicates that status (registered users won't have that mark). Here is an example: https://economics.stackexchange.com/users/30948/user30948.  See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68524/243394.

Comment: It looks like our local troll is registering accounts now...

Comment: @BrianRomanchuk: Yeah I noticed. Maybe they saw my meta post.

Comment: I am adding status review tag to this question. The previous questions you linked were answered by CM not moderators. To my best knowledge we moderators do not have access to breakdown by registered/unregistered users, and as moderators we also have to agree to privacy policy and I am not sure if sharing this would still be allowed (since the posts are old and from pre-GDPR era so I would assume that back then privacy policy was less strict - although I have no law background so it is just my guess). The status-review tag should bring this to the attention of CMs

Comment: Acknowledging this is on the CM backlog — we'll get back to you once this is assigned to one of us :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please let me share stats on registered and unregistered users' posts for the last 60 days. Below one can see almost the same data as by links in the question. I defined a "bad" post as one that has been closed, deleted, or with a negative score.

#### Questions

```
Registered Unregistered Registered Badness Unreg Badness PctRegBad PctUnregBad 
---------- ------------ ------------------ ------------- --------- ----------- 
448        47           182                27            40.63     57.45
```

#### Answers

```
Registered Unregistered Registered Badness Unreg Badness PctRegBad PctUnregBad 
---------- ------------ ------------------ ------------- --------- ----------- 
536        13           136                7             25.37     53.84
```

Comment: by the way just out of curiosity does this account for the accounts that were later discovered to be socks and merged with main account or it does not distinguish between those? I mean are those socks counted separately or after they are merged with main account only the one counts?

Comment: @1muflon1 Good question. Those that were merged are counted as one, those that were deleted do not represented in the data above at all.